# What's wrong with this Java Persistence query?

Tags: sql, jpa, netbeans, glassfish, persistence

I would like to create an query which will give me the data with the object type Organisatie.

This is what I have so far

```
public List<Organisatie> findAll() {
        return em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Contact c WHERE c.naam LIKE :custName").setParameter("custName","ORGANISATIE").getResultList();
    }
```

The command works but my list is empty ? Any ideas ? thanx

::EDIT1::
Sorry wrong copy paste.
This is the query which I use

```
public List<Organisatie> findAll() {
    return em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Contact c WHERE c.dtype LIKE :type").setParameter("type","ORGANISATIE").getResultList();
```

To give more information: I have an table which is called Contact.
It's an abstract class. The class Organisation and Person inherit from that class.

For some reason I cannot make a select directly from Organisation or Person.
That is why I'm trying it this way...Hope this clearify's my problem!

::EDIT2::

Farheq his query first did not work. But actually the query was correct!
It was the Object Type of the list which had to be changed, not List but List. So the correct method follows :

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
@Override
public List<Contact> findAll() {
    return em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Contact c WHERE c.dtype LIKE :type").setParameter("type", "%Organisatie%").getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Simple: there is no contact named "ORGANISATIE" in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have used `like` operator, I think for sure you didn't mean `=` operator, I think you want to retrieve contacts which their `naam` contains `ORGANISATIE` so put your value inside `% %`:

```
em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Contact c WHERE c.naam LIKE :custName")
.setParameter("custName","%ORGANISATIE%")
.getResultList();
```

Also above JPQL query is returning a list of `Contact` but the `findAll()` method returns `List<Organizatie>`, it is required the returning collection by `getResultList()` should be compatible with return type of the method, in this case you may change the select to select `Organizatie` objects **or** change the return type of the method to `List<Contact>` **or** depend on your entities you may convert the returned collection by above query by using  `(List<Contact>)` if is convertible to it.

Comment: doesn't seem to do the job either :(

Comment: Your query did work! The only thing I had to change was the object type in the list! Not List<Organisatie> but List<Contact>. Because Organisatie inherits from Contact! Thanx Farhęg

Comment: You are welcome, Yes, I forgot it, the collection of objects returned by getResult() should be compatible with the collection we want to map into. anyway, answer edited, thanks too and good luck.